# R - split a value into the amounts within each layer

Tags: r

I'm stumped with this one. I have a starting dataset with 2 columns: an ID and a value.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('ABC','XYZ'),
             value = c(150, 300))
```

I then define how I want to 'layer' the values (in this case, I want to split the value into layers of 100).

```
cut <- seq(0, 300, 100)
```

So, for the first record of the dataset, the value is 150. I want to split that into the amount within the range 0-100, 100-200 and 200-300.

**Starting dataset**

```
 id value
ABC   150
XYZ   300
```

**Ending dataset (after defining `cut`)**

```
 id value val_0_100 val_100_200 val_200_300
ABC   150       100          50           0
XYZ   300       100         100         100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('ABC','XYZ'),
                 value = c(150, 300))

initial_value = 0
final_value = 300
step = 100
number_of_columns = ceiling(final_value / step)  

for (i in 1:number_of_columns){
  new_col_name <- paste0("val_", step*(i-1), "_", step*i)
  df[,new_col_name] = apply(df["value"] - (step*(i-1)),1, FUN=min,100)
  df[,new_col_name] = apply(df[new_col_name],1, FUN=max,0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `data.table` and `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(id = c('ABC','XYZ'),
                 value = c(160, 230))

# Data table
dt <- data.table(df)

# Append Data multiple times based on its value
dt <- dt[rep(seq_len(nrow(dt)), ceiling(dt$value/100)), ]

# cumulative sum to be used in splitting into columns in dcast
dt[, csum := 100]
dt[, csum := cumsum(csum), by = "id"]

# Adding extra column to split into 100s and remainder
dt[, value2 := 100]
dt[csum > value, value2 := value %% 100]
dt[value < 100, value2 := value]

dt_dcast <- dcast(dt, id + value ~ csum, value.var = "value2", fill = 0)

# Rename columns as per the example shown above
colstart <- seq(0, max(dt$csum) - 100, 100)
colend <- seq(100, max(dt$csum), 100)
newname <- c("id", "value", paste0("val_",  colstart, "_", colend))
setnames(dt_dcast, names(dt_dcast), newname)
```